# Find the starting position of the <Text> component in the screen in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have an image background , on it I want to write some text which is draggable any where in the screen , Right now I am using the "react-native-draggable" component to do that job.

My goal is this find the starting position (X Y coordinates) of the text once the drag is released.
Ex: the text is "Hello world ", if i drag that all the way up and fully left , then I need to know the values of X Y = 0, 0 , if I drag that text horizontally without Y change then X,Y = say 100,0

I have read onLayout can do but I could not make it work as I just started playing with react native.

Here is My code

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground, StatusBar, Button, Dimensions,Image } from 'react-native';
import Draggable from 'react-native-draggable';

export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.maxWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width - 20;
    this.maxHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height - 40;
    this.state = {};
  }
  onDragReleaseCustom(value) {
    console.log('drag release', value.nativeEvent);
    console.log('drag release', value.nativeEvent);
  }


  onLayout = (e) => {
    console.log("working gere");
    console.log(e.nativeEvent);
    console.log("widht,height",e.nativeEvent.layout.x,e.nativeEvent.layout.y)
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <>
        <StatusBar hidden />
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <ImageBackground source={require('./assets/bg1.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
          </ImageBackground>
        </View>


        <Draggable
          minX = {15}
          minY = {15}
          maxX = {this.maxWidth}
          maxY = {this.maxHeight}
          x = {30}
          y = {112}
          onDragRelease = {this.onLayout()}>

        <View >
          <Text style={styles.customText}>Hi this is an example </Text>

        </View>
        </Draggable>

        <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
          <Button color="#f00fff" title="Save"></Button>
        </View>


      </>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Can somebody suggest better ways to achieve this. any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use PanResponder API of React native.
Use the following link to explore more about it.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/panresponder

Comment: such general pointers can be written as a comment, but not as a solution to the question, as your post doesn't actually answer the question. It's like someone asking you where the mall is and you simply point in some direction and say, "that way." A direction would be something like what Google Maps would give. That's how the answers should be.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your approach is right. You can get the layout changes using `onLayout` prop in `Text` component,

First you have to pass `onLayout` to `Text`

```
<Text onLayout={this.onLayout}>Hi this is an example</Text>
```

then you can get value using

```
onLayout = (event) => {
  const { x, y, height, width } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
  console.log(x, y);
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: On layout gives the xy position related to that text component. Ex if i touch at the letter "h" then x = 0 but if touch at the last letter "e" that gives x= say 100. But I wanna know the starting position of the text related to image background

Comment: @MadhuBabu actually it gives the related position. not like ```if I touch at the letter "h" then x = 0 but if touch at the last letter "e" that gives x=100```